# How would an Atom behave in vacuum?

Tags: energy, vacuum, atoms

Let's say I put, for example, a Hydrogen atom in vacuum where no external energies have impact on it. Would it just "sit" and exist? Or would it move around? If so, by what force?

If some energies do apply, like heat, light or gravity, would it act differently?

Comment: Is the hydrogen atom in its ground state, or is it in an excited state?

Comment: @probably_someone no idea what that means